# Generate Save Convert to TIFF PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, tiff

Please point us in right direction
We have a requirement to

1. Generate a PDF
2. Edit/Enter some fields on it
3. Save/Print the information
4. Should have a button on the pdf "Convert to TIFF" that should generate TIFF image of  that PDF

I am sure we can do 1 and 2 very easily, we are planning to use iText API. 
We dont have any clue about 4. 
Experts if you have any idea please let us know.

We are using Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of programs which do PDF to image conversion (both Open Source and Commercial). You can also use icepdf, Jpedal, Qoppa and PDFRenderer

Comment: Thanks Mark. IcePdf looks promising. I need to some reasearch about how it fits my requirement.

Comment: Icesoft have a forum for questions and Patrick is normally pretty good on replying.

Answer (score 1):

You can create, edit and fill PDF form fields using Gnostice PDFOne. PDFOne can also print PDF documents and forms. Existing documents can also [export PDF pages to image formats](http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=135&t=Convert_PDF_To_High-Resolution_Images_Using_Java). For exporting to TIFF, you will also need for Advaned Imaging IO library from Oracle (Sun). Disclaimer: I work for this company.

If you want a button **on the PDF** to export the document to TIFF, then that is not possible, as PDF specification does not describe such a feature. As mentioned earlier, any PDF document can be converted to image formats including TIFF.

DISCLAIMER: I work for Gnostice.